# LT8390A Resistor Power Ratings

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, boost, switching-regulator

I'm very new to the world of EE and I'm attempting to build my first buck/boost converter using Linear Technology's LT8390A.

For the most part I have been able to follow the datasheets instructions; however, **the one thing I'm unsure about is how to calculate the necessary power ratings for each of the resistors.**

Below is a copy of the image schematic in the datasheet that I am replicating. The resistors circled in red are the ones that I am unsure of the power rating on. Any help in both calculating the maximum power ratings for each resistor and showing out the math would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Datasheet: [LT8390A](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/8390af.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On any design figure out what the *worst case* scenario is for a resistor.

A) I would take the max Vin and divide it by the resistance of the first resistor

\$V = I*R \$ then \$ P = I^2*R\$

28/383k= 73uA or P= 73uA*383k=0.002mW Any resistor will work

B) Look at the max voltage for the CTRL pin and do the same

C) The RT pin voltage is around 1V, Vc has less than micro amps running through it (has a 10MΩ output impedance)

D) INTVcc has a 190mA max current limit

E) Same as a but use 12V and 100k, its going to be low

You get the idea, I got all this info from the datasheet and used two equations.

Comment: Thank you for this response! I knew the answer would be obvious but for some reason I was making it more difficult than needed. I think what was throwing me off was not calculating the current for the resistor, but instead assuming that all current through the circuit must be 4A (really dumb and obvious mistake!).

Comment: Quick follow-up question: with respect to the transient voltages, in the future, should I use those in my estimates for worst case scenario calculations?

Comment: If you like answers, participate in the voting system. Transient voltages will raise the temperature for a short time in the part and that temperature takes some time to bleed out through the leads. It should be considered, and ripple on DC should be considered. You could include it by rolling the ripple into your max current. You can also use a spice simulator to help you determine power over time in resistors

Answer (score 2):

Are you comfortable calculating the voltage across each resistor?

If so calculating the power using \$P=V^2/R\$ should be easy.

Comment: I appreciate the quick response! This answer coupled with @laptop2d answer makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

Calculating resistor power is of course an interesting exercise. However, there are somewhat bigger hurdles in selection of right capacitors (ESR, voltage, ripple tolerance), inductors, transistors, diodes.

This converter is no way a beginner's project. Therefore I strongly advise just go to the LinearTech [application page for this converter](http://www.linear.com/solutions/7935), and download [all design files](http://www.linear.com/docs/58639) provided by manufacturer, which includes detailed BOM. The BOM will have all proper parts, verified by experienced application engineers. Then follow the layout and parts **exactly as outlined** in the demo board, just maybe edit the board shape to fit it into your project. In this way you will save yourself a lot of troubles.

Comment: I assume this is a real project, and not a home assignment.

Comment: Indeed, I've been replicating all the steps and calculations from the datasheet and sourcing the components based on the provided specifications. I then compare the components I've found to the recommended components as part of my learning exercise. The one thing I'm curious about the most is if the electrolytic Cin capacitor  (22uF @ 63V) can be replaced with a single tantalum or a couple of ceramic (in parallel) capacitors?

Comment: @ChristopherAliotta, sure it can, the question is only in cost.